# Error:invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, function

***Question: Write a C++ program to reverse an array using functions***

The presented code below returns the following error:

> Error: Invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript b[n-i-1]=arr[i];

Please tell the solution to the problem i.e. how to remove the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int arr,int n)
{
    int b[100];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        b[n-i-1]=arr[i];
        cout<<b[i]<<"\t";
    }
}

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    int a[100],n;

    cout<<"Type the number of elements in an array:\n";
    cin>>n;

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number "<<j+1<<endl;
        cin>>a[j];
    }

    reverse(a[100],n);

    getch();

}
```

Comment: Look at `int reverse(int arr,int n)`.  is `arr` declared as an array?

Comment: `int reverse(int arr,int n)` think what you missed with `arr`

Comment: Inspection Checklists.  Use them.  Create a list of common issues (such as not using [] for array parameters).  Take the first issue, then scan your code for instances of the issue.  Repeat for the remaining issues.  Update the checklist after compiling.  Use the Inspection Checklist before posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: BTW: Even if you declare the array parameter correctly,  `reverse(a[100],n);` would access the array out of bounds, trying to pass an `int`. You probably want to write `reverse(a,n);` there, after fixing the primary problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake passing the array as a parameter of the function `reverse ()`. The correct way to pass an array as a parameter is to pass it as a pointer to the first element, that's what really is:

```
reverse(a,n);
```

You have to change your function definition too:

```
int reverse(int arr[],int n)
```

Take a look at [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays-functions) tutorial for more information but I recommend you a good book on C/C++ programming like [How to Program in C++ (Deitel, Deitel)](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Deitel-C-How-to-Program-10th-Edition/9780134448237.html)

Another correction: You need to fill all the `b` array before printing it. I suggest you for example to add another loop after the first `for` in `reverse` to print the elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! It worked. Yes sir, I am following two authors:Deital and Deital and Robert Lafore.